# Show image from url and also retrieve header

Tags: php, image

I have created a php function which returns random images.

I am using image/jpeg header to directly write the image to the response.

To keep track of which images I am returning, I am sending the ID of the image in the response header. The screenshot shows the details. (See the marked header called tryid)

[image]

Now, I need to show this image in an image tag.

If I write this

```
<img src='<?php echo $remote_url?>' />
```

then I can show the image, **but I need the header information as well.**

I tried using curl so that I can get both the image as well as read the header, but this code did not show the image in the image tag.

```
    <?php
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); // return HTTP headers with response
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // return the response rather than output it

    $resp = curl_exec($ch);

    ?>

    <img src='<?php echo $resp; ?>' />
```

To sum up, I am trying to show the image in image tag as well as read the request header.

I am showing the output of var_dump($resp) in another screenshot.[image]

Comment: Could you show the output of `var_dump($resp)` ?

Comment: @roberto06 modified my question to include the output you requested

Comment: Why not use both your solutions ? You could request only the header with cURL (with the `CURLOPT_NOBODY` option), and also hotlink your image URL with `<?php echo $remote_url; ?>.

Comment: @roberto06 Every time I send a request to the remote URL it sends a different image. So I probably cannot use both curl and <?php echo $remote_url; ?>

Comment: I understand... You're going to have to separate the header fro,m the body in your cURL return. Try taking a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29783752/php-curl-to-simultaneously-save-image-get-header-response), I think it might help you.